# Why does /bin/sh hang when ran via execl on this particular script?

Tags: c, unix, pipe, sh

Can you give me some ideas on the following code? The code runs but it doesn't exit. The other string, `s="ls -1"` works well. Running the shell snippet via `sh(1)` works just fine also.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd[2];

    char *s = "ls -1 \"/usr/bin\" | while IFS= read -r fp\ndo\ncat <<- EOF\n\t$fp\nEOF\ndone;";
    //char *s = "ls -1";


    pipe(fd);

    switch(fork()) {
        case 0:
            close(fd[1]);
            dup2(fd[0], 0);
            execl("/bin/sh", "sh", NULL);
            close(fd[0]);
        break;
        default:
            close(fd[0]);
            write(fd[1], s, strlen(s) + 1);
            close(fd[1]);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the child. **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the original file descriptors from `pipe()` as soon as possible. In particular, that means _before_ using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) family of functions. The rule also applies with either `dup()` or [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) with `F_DUPFD`.

Comment: In this case, the `close(fd[0]);` needs to be before the `execl()` — remember, if it is successful, `execl()` never returns (it only returns on failure).  You should arguably have an error report and `exit(1);` or similar after the `execl()`; at the moment, you report success even on failure.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I was wondering about the order of  `execl` and `close(fd[0]);` and your comments make sense, however, switching their order still doesn't work. It behaves the same way, doesn't exit.

Comment: See my answer — yes, I agree that the comments aren't the solution to your problem, though the close after the exec is not executed and there should be an error message there.

Comment: Might also be related to the big number of heredocs and tmp files.

Comment: It's much easier on humans to use semi-colons as a separator rather than newlines: `while IFS= read -r fp; do cat`.  If you're going to use unnecessary quotes, use single quotes: `"ls -l '/usr/bin'...` so you don't need to escape them.

Comment: are you sure that it hangs, or it just fails to print the cursor after it had run?  anyways, **a)** you shouldn't write the terminating NUL byte to the child (change `strlen(s) + 1` to `strlen(s)`) **b)** you should [`wait(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) for your child.

Comment: please also mention (in your Q) your system; I'm not able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: regarding: `switch(fork()) {`  The function `fork()` has three kinds of returned values:: 1) <0 means an error occurred 2) ==0 means the child process is running  3) >0 means the parent is running.  The code needs to check for all three conditions

Answer (score 3):

When I was converting my comments into an answer, I tested the proposed change, and it didn't fix the problem.  One fix that ought to work is to add `; exit` at the end of the string, even though that's tantamount to cheating.  However, testing that also shows it doesn't finish; it is as if the `ls` isn't terminating.

I went to another terminal to see whether the processes for `ls` or `pipe97` (my name for your code) were still around; they weren't.

- Try typing `ps` to your 'hung' process.

You should get a normal output and your prompt.

Because the parent doesn't wait for the child to exit, the prompt is lost somewhere in the output from `ls` (which is quite long and produced quite slowly).  Redirect the output to `/dev/null` and you'll see your prompt.

- The best fix is probably to add a `wait()` loop in the parent process, so it doesn't exit until after the child does.

```
#include <sys/wait.h>

…
int corpse;
int status;
while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
    ;
```

While debugging, you can print `corpse` and `status` so you can see what's going on.

---

I observe that this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55766280/why-does-bin-sh-hang-when-ran-via-execl-on-this-particular-script/55766561#comment98207025_55766280) (without its preamble) remains valid:

> …the `close(fd[0]);` needs to be before the `execl()` — remember, if it is successful, `execl()` never returns (it only returns on failure). You should arguably have an error report and `exit(1);` or similar after the `execl()`; at the moment, you report success even on failure.

By itself, the [Rule of Thumb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55766280/why-does-bin-sh-hang-when-ran-via-execl-on-this-particular-script/55766561#comment98207009_55766280) comment is valid, but it is not actually applicable to this code — unclosed pipe descriptors aren't causing the trouble, even though one pipe descriptor that should have been closed was not closed.

Answer (score 1):

@WilliamPursell Thanks, you're right. I wasn't focusing on that on this example.

@user3629249 I'm aware I'm not doing proper error checking, thank you!

@mosvy It was OpenBSD, indeed it ran on a Mac.

This version works:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd[2];

    char *s = "ls -1 '/usr/bin' | while IFS= read -r fp\ndo\ncat <<- EOF\n\t$fp\nEOF\ndone;";
    //char *s = "ls -1";


    pipe(fd);

    switch(fork()) {
        case 0:
            close(fd[1]);
            dup2(fd[0], 0);
            execl("/bin/sh", "sh", NULL);
            close(fd[0]);
        break;
        default:
            close(fd[0]);
            write(fd[1], s, strlen(s));
            close(fd[1]);
            wait(NULL);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It was the `wait(2)` that did it. I remember I did `wait(2)` at some point, however I think I screwed the `close(1)` order so it was blocking.

Anyway, problem fixed, thanks!